# EE Multi Site Question

Tags: multi-site-manager

Thanks for your help.  We are about to build a solution for a client and we will use the multi-site addon.  These six sites will all be identical except that each will have unique content assets and be on their own domains.  Assuming that all the sites will use the same templates and design, what is involved in adding a new site down the road?  Is it pretty easy for a dev to knock out?  Can the hours be roughed?

Comment: This is an overly broad question. As per our FAQ: "Questions must be answerable (e.g. no feature requests), and must not lead to open ended discussions (e.g. no "which add-on is the best" type questions, unless they have a specific use case described)." Please edit your question to be more specific and answerable...

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of building out an MSM site as you describe, but that's not really the point of SE. If you have troubles building this then post specific questions on the issues at hand here and we'll gladly help you out. If you share your templates across {embed="default_site:_inc/_header"} that is where you'll want to start. Then when you create a new "site" with MSM then you'll need to copy over the templates over. Start with one and go from there and once you get that worked out then post additional questions from there.

Be sure to study the MSM documentation here:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/

Also Boyink has a helpful tutorial here as well:

http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials/comments/splitting-a-site-out-of-an-ee-msm-installation

Hope that helps!